# About ruby popen

Tags: ruby, popen

I am learning ruby popen, and I am interested in a simple program:

```
pipe = IO.popen("-","w+")
if pipe
  pipe.puts "Get a job!"
  STDERR.puts "Child says: #{pipe.gets.chomp}"
else
  STDERR.puts "Dad says: #{gets.chomp}"
  puts "OK"
end
```

Then the produces look like that:

```
Dad says: Get a job!
Child says: OK
```

But, when I update the code by removing STDOUT:

```
pipe = IO.popen("-","w+")
if pipe
  pipe.puts "Get a job!"
  puts "Child says: #{pipe.gets.chomp}"
else
  puts "Dad says: #{gets.chomp}"
  puts "OK"
end
```

Then result changes to this:

```
Child says: Dad says: Get a job!
```

It misses "OK"! So, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `STDERR.`, `puts` write the output to the stdout. stdout in the child process is pipe. Anything written to the stdout is not printed, but sent to the pipe.

The child process write 2 lines.

1. `Dad say: Get a job!`
2. `OK`

The parent process read a line (Dad say: Get a job!), and print that.

```
Child says: Dad say: Get a job!
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -- read from the pipe (stdout of child process).
```

If you also want print `OK`, call `pipe.gets` twice or use `pipe.read` to read all output of children:

```
pipe = IO.popen("-","w+")
if pipe
  pipe.puts "Get a job!"
  puts "Child says: #{pipe.read}"
else
  puts "Dad says: #{gets.chomp}"
  puts "OK"
end
```

Comment: @user2886717, Any reason of unaccept? Please let me know if there's wrong with the answer.

Comment: Don't worry, I have accepted your answer just now. :-)